# Why do I get Code Analysis CA1062 on an out parameter in this code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis, fxcop, ca1062

I have a very simple code (simplified from the original code - so I know it's not a very clever code) that when I compile in Visual Studio 2010 with Code Analysis gives me warning CA1062: Validate arguments of public methods.

```
public class Foo
{
    protected static void Bar(out int[] x)
    {
        x = new int[1];
        for (int i = 0; i != 1; ++i)
            x[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

The warning I get:

> CA1062 : Microsoft.Design : In
>   externally visible method 'Foo.Bar(out
>   int[])', validate local variable
>   '(*x)', which was reassigned from
>   parameter 'x', before using it.

I don't understand why do I get this warning and how can I resolve it without suppressing it? Can `new` return `null`? Is this a Visual Studio 2010 bug?

**UPDATE**

I've decided to open [a bug report on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560049/getting-ca1062-on-an-out-parameter).

Comment: I wonder if the problem is elsewhere ...

Comment: Again no repro.  There's nothing to validate.  You've posted other code analysis warnings that don't repro. If you've made any config changes then be sure to document them.

Comment: @Hans Passant, are you sure you're running all microsoft code analysis rules in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: I don't see anybody else repro-ing this either.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I can repro it without problems. I have a project in a solution that repro it every compilation without a doubt. I'm not sure that everyone can't repro that, you're the only one that wrote he tried and failed.

Comment: I *have* reproduced this in Visual Studio 2010 Premium.  I just pasted in the class as given in the question, turned on *Microsot All Rules* in the settings and analysed the project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've reproduced this in Visual Studio 2010 Premium with the code exactly as given and with *Microsoft All Rules* enabled in the analysis settings.

It looks like this is a bug (see bottom of here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182182.aspx).  It is complainng that you are not checking that `x` is not null before using it, but it's on `out` parameter so there is no input value to check!

Answer (score 8):

It's easier to show than to describe :

```
public class Program
{
    protected static int[] testIntArray;

    protected static void Bar(out int[] x)
    {
        x = new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            x[i] = 1; // NullReferenceException
        }
    }

    protected static void Work()
    {
        Bar(out testIntArray);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t1 = new Thread(Work);
        t1.Start();

        while (t1.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
        {
            testIntArray = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And the correct way is :

```
    protected static void Bar(out int[] x)
    {
        var y = new int[100];

        for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            y[i] = 1;
        }

        x = y;
    }
```

Comment: ok, but why is the correct way correct?  Or do you say it's correct because there is no warning thrown in code analysis?

Comment: What you've shown is certainly an important point (if x might be accessed by multiple threads) but I don't think this is what CA1062 is intended to highlight. If you read the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182182.aspx, it's obvious this is intended for `ref` parameters and is just a standard "check it's not null before using it" rule. It's a bug that it's being applied to `out` parameters.  Does this actually prevent the CA1062 warning?

Comment: @gmagana: The correct way is thread safe and won't throw NullReferenceException no matter what.

Comment: @Daniel: "All reference arguments...", out is considered reference argument too.

Comment: Yeah, ok.  But `out` is an output only reference argument while `ref` is input/output reference argument.  There's no need to perform *input validation* (which is what CA1062 is about) on an output-only parameter.

Comment: The only difference between `out` and `ref` is that you have to assign a value to the parameter, it's like a contract. When you access `x`  by using the indexer you're actually reading it.

Comment: But it's not possible to access it using the indexer until *after* you've assigned it a value *inside* the method.  If you try, it will fail to compile.  There is no way to pass information into a method via an `out` parameter.